# Different action url for a button within one form

Tags: html

There are some buttons within a form. I want one of them to use another url as an action url. But I want it to be within that form, I don't want to and can't create another form for that.

How can I do that?

Comment: Well, HTML can't do this. PHP or JavaScript can do this (albeit hacky with PHP)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JavaScript for this

```
<form name="my_form" method="post">
   Name <input type="text" name="person_name" /><br />
   <input type="button" value="Button 1" name="button_1" onclick="return target_btn1();">
   <input type="button" value="Button 2" name="button_2" onclick="return target_btn2();">
</form>

<script>
function target_btn1() {
    document.my_form.action = "whatever.php"; //Trigger action
    document.my_form.submit(); //Submit action performed
    return true;
}

function target_btn2() {
    document.my_form.action = "whatever2.php"; //Trigger action
    document.my_form.submit(); //Submit action performed
    return true;
}
</script>
```

Comment: how do I change the method (get, post) for a form the same way?

Comment: you can try that. I am not 100% it will work though.
You can do it using jQuery, but I would not go down that route until you have at least tried it the first way. I would attempt to mock up the code quickly to see if it works, but I am unable to access JSFiddle.net from here at the moemnt...

Answer (score 5):

HTML5 (IE>9), provides the [`formaction` attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_formaction.asp).

```
 <form action="demo_form.asp" method="get">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button><br>
  <button type="submit" formaction="demo_admin.asp">Submit as admin</button>
</form>
```

> A form with two submit buttons. The first submit button submits the
>   form data to "demo_form.asp", and the second submits to
>   "demo_admin.asp".

Answer (score 2):

add an onclick event to the button calling a javascript function.
then, in that function, set the action for the form and then submit. 
something like this:

```
<input type="button" id="blah" value="Press Me" onclick="javascript:SetForm();">
```

Then, in javascript:

```
    function SetForm()
{
  document.formname.action = '';
  document.formname.submit();
}
```